# Laravel 6 retain session between two servers and subdomains

Tags: laravel

I have 2 instances of Laravel running and I want to retain the session between them (including subdomains)

This used to work just fine, but I did change servers causing it to fail and I just simply cannot understand why.

I have:
Session domain set to same and includes .domain.com for the wildcard subdomain purposes
app key same
cookie name is the same
both are using cookie as driver (tried redis where redis is being the same instance of course as well with no luck)

Have cleared config caches, even manually

When I compare cookies between the two servers, the other one has longer cookie (the one which is named in session.php)

Shouldn't these be the same to the letter (cookie's contents that is)?

I can't understand why another one is getting overwritten with longer one (I log in on server 1, refresh server 2 view and I am not logged in, instead faulty cookie gets created).

Any tips, ideas etc I could look into would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Cache was not clearing properly, if someone encounters this, make sure artisan command can clear the cache files with the right file rights.